# I am having trouble making a directory while iterating through a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, mkdir

I am new to Java and I am trying to tie together separate code, "Making a directory" and "reading a text file". This is what I have thus far:

```
    import java.io.*;

public class FileDir {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean dirFlag = false;

    try {
        File myFile = new File("Michael.txt");
        File folder = new File("/Users/chucknorr/Desktop/");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (fileReader);

        String line= null;
        while((line= reader.readLine()) != null) {
          dirFlag = folder.mkdir(line);

        }
        reader.close();

    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

I understand that is not correct, it is my failed attempt to tie the code together. **dirFlag = folder.mkdir(line);**

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the error as well. So that we know what is happening.

Comment: What are trying to do? From the code, it seems like you're trying to read in "Michael.txt" and each line of Michael.txt is a folder name to be created under "/Users/chucknorr/Desktop/". Is this your intention?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such method `File#mkdir(String)`

Instead you could use...

```
File subFolder = new File(folder, line);
if (!subFolder.mkdirs()) {
    // Deal with situations where the sub folder wasn't created
}
```

For example.

Take a closer look at the [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) Java Docs